# bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Hi i am currently at chapter 6 of michael hartl's tutorial.
After i managed to get it to heroku, `bundle exec rake db:migrate` doesnt work and it keeps giving me the error below. 
I've tried adding several usernames and passwords to the database.yml file but to no avail.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
PG::Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "amuudiqbgwhemy"
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:881:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:881:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:881:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_c
onnection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connec
tion'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in check
out'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in conne
ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_conne
ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:910:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've pushed the app to heroku you should try running (from your local terminal)

heroku run rake db:migrate

Contextually, you don't have to set a username/password in the database.yml file as the Postgres database that you're using is setup via config variables set by your use of the postgres add-on.

Comment: I've tried that but it gives Timeout awaiting process.. do u have an idea why is that so?